# Getting error while deploying Enterprise Bot App

Tags: command-line-interface, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to deploy my new enterprise bot app by following the steps in the documented steps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-enterprise-template-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

But, unfortunately I am getting this error:
With msbot 4.3.2 and later, the only AZ CLI prerequisite is having an AZ CLI version >= 2.0.53. If you have the botservice extension installed as well, please remove this via "az extension remove --name botservice".
Checking az botservice version
You need to upgrade your AZ CLI version to >= 2.0.53.
You can install the latest AZ CLI from https://aka.ms/az-cli-download

Although, I did install the latest AZ CLI [2.0.58]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/962) with `msbot` reading the AZ CLI version wrong.

You have two options:

1. A new version (4.3.3) of `msbot` was released that should fix this, so you can use `npm i -g msbot` to upgrade to the latest `msbot` and use the 2.0.58 AZ CLI, or
2. Downgrade to the [2.0.57 AZ CLI](https://azurecliprod.azureedge.net/msi/azure-cli-2.0.57.msi).

I tested it just now and can confirm the 4.3.3 update fixes this:

[image]

[image]

[image]